# Hi im trying to change user ScriptPath to be same as their reporting to user/manager

Tags: powershell

```
Get-ADUser -Identity user -Properties Manager, ScriptPath

Set-ADUser -Identity user –scriptPath
```

I am quite new to powershell, trying to add user `scriptpath` to be same as another ID

can this be done using  `Set-ADUser` to change user  ScriptPath to be same as their reporting to user/manager in one line?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Get-ADuser "user" -Properties Manager, ScriptPath | Where-Object { Set-ADUser "$($_.SamAccountName)" -ScriptPath "$((Get-ADuser "$($_.Manager)" -Properties ScriptPath).ScriptPath)" }
```

Using `$($var.Object)` allows you to use a PSObject inside of quotes. I usually use `"$($var.Object)"` to prevent from space and special characters errors.

Here you can also see that you can use a command as a variable : `(Get-ADuser "$($_.Manager)" -Properties ScriptPath).ScriptPath`. It is supposed to return exactly the content of ScriptPath.

Hope it helps.